# Embedded YouTube video lags and stutters

Tags: android, performance, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have a non-PlayStore app for Tablet devices where I have embedded YouTube videos in a FullScreenActivity. Code is pretty standard as per the documentation. However, I find the video playback quite laggy and it keeps buffering. To figure out what's happening, I started measuring things.

Device is Rockchip RK3368, 1GB Ram, 15.6 inch IPS display, 1920x1080, Android 6.0

1) Bandwidth - Have a 50 Mbps connection, face no problem with YouTube in any other device.

2) Memory - The device does have 1 GB memory, it may be less but I have no app other than stock ones installed and when I check for free memory it is generally more than 250 MB.

3) Processing power - It's an 8 core RK3368 CPU, however, after turning 'Show CPU usage' on, I see the device (the number for average cpu usage for time interval 1 minute) goes from about 5 to 20 or higher. This is when everything starts hanging in the tablet. Pressing back button or home button takes many many seconds to even register (that is show the ripple animation).

On closing the activity, the tablet is back to normal in about half a minute.
Turning hardwareAccelerated to true has helped a little but it is still unusable.

Please let me know how to improve the performance.
Please bear with me. I will provide any code/info/run tests if you need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More information would be needed to understand what's going on, 1 GB ram is kinda low though, I wouldn't expect buttery smooth interaction. Maybe using a different player will help you solve the issue https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and let you know.

Comment: Figured out a working option using YouTube in webview. Faced some problems there too but eventually worked out a usable solution. Major problem was the Android System Webview was outdated. It was version 54. Updated it to latest beta v66 solved all the performance issues.

Comment: Very well. The alternative player i suggested is actually based on WebView.